# WooCommerce Get the product object from the product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, page-title

I am making a code to get product object from product title.
I am reading product title from my notepad file and passing it to Wordpress function.

Below is a function in which `$pval` is a product title.

```
 $productdetail_by_title = get_page_by_title($pval, OBJECT, 'product');
 print_r($productdetail_by_title);
 exit;
```

product title is something like this: `200x Slopupovací pleťová Rusk`

But I am not able to get product object. If i pass statically this title like this:

```
$productdetail_by_title = get_page_by_title("200x Slopupovací pleťová Rusk", OBJECT, 'product');
print_r($productdetail_by_title);
exit;
```

Then I am able to get product object. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [**`get_page_by_title()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) WordPress function, you will not get the [**`WC_Product`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) objet but if it's working you will get the [**`WP_Post`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object.

So here is a custom built function that will output the WC_Product object, if the title matches with a real product title:

```
function get_wc_product_by_title( $title ){
    global $wpdb;

    $post_title = strval($title);

    $post_table = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    $result = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT ID
        FROM $post_table
        WHERE post_title LIKE '$post_title'
        AND post_type LIKE 'product'
    ");

    // We exit if title doesn't match
    if( empty( $result[0] ) ) 
        return;
    else
        return wc_get_product( intval( $result[0] ) );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**EXAMPLE USAGE:**

```
// Your title set in a variable
$title = "200x Slopupovací pleťová Rusk";

// Using our custom function to get an instance of the WC_Product object
$product_obj = get_wc_product_by_title( $title );

// Testing the output
print_r($product_obj);
```

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: Why did you use LIKE in this string `AND post_type LIKE 'product'`? shouldn't the `product_type` exactly match `product`?

Comment: @RWS "product" is not the product type **but the WordPress  custom "post_type"** when querying the "wp_posts" table… The product type is defined as a specific term in custom taxonomy "product_type". There is many product types as "simple", "variable", "external"…

Comment: I actually misspelled, i meant post_type. Yes, you are right, I totally forgot about other product types, thank you for clarification. it worked for me only when I changed the respective part of the query to `post_title LIKE '%$post_title%'`